Can in-memory-sqlite3 database ever get faster than C++ data structure
I have a use case where I manage an array of structs. This looks like an SQL table. It also is associated with queries based on various properties of the structures in the array. Similar to SQL querying.
I was wondering if SQLITE in-memory database can replace my array of structures giving me better speed and less code since I can reuse SQLITE features like querying instead of writing functions to traverse the data structure myself. I hope indexing from SQLITE gives me additional speed without reinventing the wheel.
However, in my initial testing, SQLITE in-memory database is almost 12-30x slower than C++ data structures, just for insertions.
I tried a few optimizations from this SO question, but none seem to help much.
Improve INSERT-per-second performance of SQLite
My question is can SQLITE ever beat C++ data structures?
Here is a sample code in both cases.
Please NOTE: I am not doing several optimizations like batching the inserts, adding indexing after inserting all entries etc. as in real-time, inserts and reads happen interleaved. I am trying to see if the algorithms in SQLITE implementation can optimize my querying (not in the examples below) to the extent that it performs better than simple data structure implementations in C++.
Ex: If I poll based on prop3 and prop5, implementing indexing requires processing a query myself. Just trying to offload it to SQLITE.
With C++ Data structures.
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

struct item_t {
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned int b;
    bool prop1;
    bool prop2;
    bool prop3;
    bool prop4;
    bool prop5;
};

typedef std::map<unsigned int, item_t> items_t;

int main() {
    srand(RAND_SEED);
    items_t data;
    unsigned int delta = 0x100000000 / ITERATIONS, randInt;
    unsigned int count;

    // Create `ITERATIONS segments with random properties
    for (unsigned int i = 0, a = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i, a += delta) {
        randInt = rand();
        data[a] = {
            a, a + delta - 1,
            bool(randInt & 16),
            bool(randInt &  8),
            bool(randInt &  4),
            bool(randInt &  2),
            bool(randInt &  1)
        };
    }

    printf("Inserted %d entries\n", data.size());
    return 0;
}

With SQLITE In-Memory database
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <string.h>


static int sqliteExecCallback(void *unused, int count, char **data, char **columns)
{
    for (int idx = 0; idx < count; idx++) {
        printf("%s\n", data[idx]);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    srand(RAND_SEED);
    unsigned int delta = 0x100000000 / ITERATIONS, randInt;

    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;

    rc = sqlite3_open(":memory:", &db);

    if (rc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        return(0);
    }
    rc = sqlite3_exec(
        db,
        "PRAGMA synchronous = OFF;"
        "PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY",
        NULL, NULL, &zErrMsg
    );
    if (rc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't set PRAGMAs: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        return(0);
    }

    rc = sqlite3_exec(
        db,
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DATA("
        "a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        "b INTEGER,"
        "prop1 INTEGER,"
        "prop2 INTEGER,"
        "prop3 INTEGER,"
        "prop4 INTEGER,"
        "prop5 INTEGER"
        ");"
        "CREATE INDEX DATA_prop1_idx on DATA(prop1);"
        "CREATE INDEX DATA_prop2_idx on DATA(prop2);"
        "CREATE INDEX DATA_prop3_idx on DATA(prop3);"
        "CREATE INDEX DATA_prop4_idx on DATA(prop4);"
        "CREATE INDEX DATA_prop5_idx on DATA(prop5);",
        0, 0, &zErrMsg
    );

    if (rc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't execute create table: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        return(0);
    }

    char sql[512] = "INSERT INTO DATA (a, b, prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4, prop5)";
    int len = strlen(sql);
    for (unsigned int i = 0, a = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i, a += delta) {
        randInt = rand();
        sprintf(
            sql + len,
            " VALUES (%u, %u, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d);",
            a, a + delta - 1,
            bool(randInt & 16),
            bool(randInt &  8),
            bool(randInt &  4),
            bool(randInt &  2),
            bool(randInt &  1)
        );
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, 0, 0, &zErrMsg);
    }

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DATA", sqliteExecCallback, 0, &zErrMsg);

    if (false && rc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't execute SELECT COUNT(*): %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }
    return 0;
}

To run
g++ -std=c++20 -O3 -march=native -DITERATIONS=2000000 -DRAND_SEED=1 sqlite.cpp -l sqlite3 > comp.log 2>&1
/bin/time -f "sqlite,%S,%U,%e,%M,%X" --append -o metrics.csv ./a.out > run.log 2>&1

g++ -std=c++20 -O3 -march=native -DITERATIONS=2000000 -DRAND_SEED=1 cpp.cpp -l sqlite3 > comp.log 2>&1
/bin/time -f "cpp,%S,%U,%e,%M,%X" --append -o metrics.csv ./a.out > run.log 2>&1

Sample runtimes
     -  SysTime  UserTime  RealTime    MaxMem  ExitStatus
   cpp     0.09      0.62      0.71  128928.0         0.0
sqlite     0.06     25.01     25.07  196864.0         0.0

NOTE: I cannot batch my SQL queries as the requests are external, but open to other optimizations.
Update, using sqlite3_prepare_v2 I was able to get 8x improvement and the runtime is down to 3-4 seconds now.

My question is can SQLITE ever beat C++ data structures? Normally, no, Sqlite cannot beat well written C++ algorithm. The reason for that: Sqlite is like an interpreted language, it is build upon a language lexer and some microcode. However, you can increase the execution speed of your snippet a lot by using properly prepared statements and single transaction. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/q/1711631

Besides not using transactions and prepared statements to speed up insertions, you have... a lot... of indexes. Do you really need all of them? Each one adds another table that has to be updated whenever you insert or update a row. At the very least it might be faster to create them after inserting a bunch of data.

It always boils down to what is being executed exactly. Your code is not optimal, because your
" VALUES (%u, %u, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d);"

line makes sure that every insert will happen separately. Instead of commands like
insert into sometable(...)
values(...);

you will need
insert into sometable(...)
values
(...),
(...),
(...),
...
(...);

The reason is simple. Each and every insert you were running is converted into a transaction and then that transaction is being handled as a transaction, so if you insert 1000 lines, you will have 1000 separate transactions to handle and that adds up, see https://sqlite.org/forum/info/f832398c19d30a4a
Instead, you should build a queue of items you want to insert  and periodically build a batch of records to be inserted. It is up to you to decide whether you want your periods be time-dependend (each minute, for example) and/or size dependent (100 records, for example), but since inserts are the point of bleed here, first convert your code to run batch-inserts.
Then compare it with C++. I'm skeptical about in-memory SQLite ever becoming faster than any other kind of data structure, but you can definitely make it much more faster than it currently is.

I Agree with the sentiment, the OP cansqlite3_prepare_* his query for optimizing it for multiple queries ... also print-format isn't really the "SQL" way to parameterize query values, using sqlite3's parameterize API is technically more correct and safer

I can not batch SQL queries as the requests come from external sources. But will try sqlite3_prepare.

@Krishna even in that case you could accumulate them into a queue and periodically batch-insert. But, your for (unsigned int i = 0, a = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i, a += delta) { clearly suggests that you already receive batches. Also, John makes a good point about parameterizing via the API rather than the way you currently do it.

@Lajos Arpad, Will try the parameters. But this is a benchmark to test the performance. Since the queries don't come in batches in realtime, did not do that optimization.

@Krishna you do not have to insert the record at the exact time when you receive it. This is what I have explained you twice. You can insert the new item that you receive into a queue instead of inserting it into SQLite. and then periodically (every 3 minutes, for example) you need to check this queue whether it contains elements and if so, then batch insert. I have the impression that you completely ignore this idea, even though it's key to the performance of insertion.

@Lajos Arpad, do you mean to manage a cache myself and flush when there is a read query? I will do that in the actual application. But I don't have the numbers from the actual workload to say how many I can batch in real-time before a read query comes. So did not factor that in the benchmark above.

@Krishna I advocate the use of write caching, yes. Your in-memory data structure would be a temporary place to store the items you want to insert as records, so you do not pile up lots of individual requests to SQLite and cause troubles on your performance, but, instead, reduce the number of transaction handling that was the culprit of your performance issues.

@Lajos Arpad, I do not need any actual database (fil or anything), in memory is sufficient for me, similar to C++ data structures. Is there any setting in SQLITE that does this caching by itself? Say does not write to actual database until there is a need (a read query)

@Krishna maybe this source would interest you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763184/how-we-can-ensure-caching-to-reduce-file-system-write-cycle-for-sqlite-databases

There may be reasons why an "in memory database" might be faster, but it's rare.
The thing is, first and foremost, you're adding complexity. Maybe not for yourself, but in terms of code getting executed.
Now, when you store data in a C++ program, you're usually looking at the data and what you need to do, and select a suitable data structure to hold it. This will generally give you efficient handling -- maybe even very efficient, but oftentimes it's not worth the effort trying to squeeze the last bit of performance out of it.
Databases aren't magic; if your C++ code is already efficient, adding a ton of complexity isn't going to improve it. Databases are very flexible, but this comes at a cost. Your C++ code isn't going to be that flexible -- you'll have to hardcode every query -- but it's going to be simple and straightforward. Chances are, by the time your C++ code returns the result, the database is still analyzing your query...
I don't know whether your DB engine can do prepared statements -- but did you notice that you're creating a database command for each insert, that the database will have to parse first, before it can even think about how to do the actual insert? So, you're printing a string, the database analyzes the string -- and while this is going on, the C++ code has already inserted the data. And we haven't even gotten into the complexities of a database table.
Putting a database engine into your program can help you if you're very, very lazy. Like you just want to put your stuff into a huge std::vector and loop over it to look up things; stuff like that might help you to make a database engine look better.

Sure databases are adding additional complexity like parsing etc. But I thought indexing would compensate for that. Do you think the time lost in query processing can be offset by indexing benefits and may be other database magic if any?

@Krishna the thing is -- you are using a map in your code, which IS indexing. That's why I had the paragraph about looking at the data and what you want to do with it, and then choosing the data structure... and I'm generally reluctant to just assume things like "database magic" :-) In the past, I've also had multiple "indexes" by storing smartpointers to the data in multiple containers...

I don't know whether your DB engine can do prepared statements Sqlite can.
